# how to use a php variable from other php script in a function()

Tags: php, variables, joomla, include, scope

I've searched stackoverflow and some others sites and tried new code combinations for a few hours now, but I give up..
I've 2 php files, one called getimages.php and the other called mod_slidepluslight.php i'm using Joomla as CMS and made a slideshow module with lightbox, now I want to retrieve images from folders inside Joomla through the module parameters set in an .xml file. I did this by using this code:

```
$imagePath = $params->get('imagePath', 'banners');
```

Now when I try to declare this variable and use it in my code it doesn't do anything.

```
function returnimages($relPath = "/KVD/images/") { 
$dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $relPath . $imagePath;
```

The $imagePath should either be added after /KVD/images/......./ or where it is now. The whole code of getimages.php looks like this:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

$imagePath = $params->get('imagePath', 'banners/');

function returnimages($relPath = "/KVD/images/") { 
$dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $relPath . $imagePath; 
$files = array(); 
$curimage = 0; 
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) { 
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/', $file)){ 
print_r ('galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'. $relPath . $file .'";'); 
$curimage++; 
} 
} 

closedir($handle); 
} 
return($files); 
} 

print 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript 
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
```

Thanks, Koen.

Answer (score 0):

yoo call $imagePath inside a function but $imagePath is out of function scope! you can send the $imagePath as a parameter to the function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean that I should add my $imagePath =.... inside my function?

Comment: This is a possible solution. Another one define the function like this: function returnimages($relPath = "/KVD/images/", $imagePath) and then when you cal it returnimages(null, $imagePath)

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind the scope of a variable : your `returnimages()` function won't be able to access the $imagePath varibale until you globalize it or pass it through the function.

Just add, on the top of your function code :

```
global $imagePath;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, i've now set is this way but it stil isn't working. 
$imagePath = $params->get('imagePath', 'banners/');

function returnimages($relPath = "/KVD/images/") { 
global $imagePath;
$dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $relPath . $imagePath;

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a different approach. When creating a module that will utilise another script, this other script should be a helper.

Have a look at:

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5

If you make the contents of getimages.php available as a helper, as described in the link above, you will be able to utilise your parameters in that script.